# Which sounds, if any, induce vocal strain?

Tags: phonetics

I use voice recognition software as a keyboard replacement. I recently replaced the word 'enter' with 'eek' to trigger an enter keystroke. The word 'eek' has much better recognition accuracy. Although, it seems to induce vocal strain much faster.

Is there any documentation regarding which sounds or sound transitions produce vocal strain? If not, is there a rule of thumb I could use?

Answer (score -1):

No language sounds cause vocal strain, which can be caused by talking too much, more likely by talking "the wrong way" (not conversationally, but shouting or lecturing). It is possible that if one's vocal folds have been injured that a particular *way* of squeaking out "eek" will hurt, since "eek" is not a normal word pronounced like "seek" without the "s". Even if you speak Somali or Arabic, which have a lot of laryngeal consonants, it's not the language or words that cause vocal strain.

Comment: I really appreciate this insight and will research it further. Personally, I don't think I'm shouting or lecturing. Also, I don't think my vocal cords have been injured. It might just be perception. Even if other languages exist with these sounds, I don't see how this would preclude it causing more pain. I just might be using it more than the average speaker in either language. Or, it could be an effect of repetition.